# PHP Inventory database design

Tags: php, transfer, inventory, stock

I am working on a PHP Inventory application. But I'm stuck in the database design. The logic is:

1. Catagories
2. 1 catagory contains many products
3. One Product have many sizes of bottles like 300 ml, 500ml, 1 litre and each size have its own price
4. Product will be stored or moved to 2 or 3 locations. Like godown, counter etc.

The problem is if I enter 6 units of a product from godown to counter, how can I represent that through the database tables? I have designed the database but I can't figure out the logic how to transfer or move a stock. Here is the design:

![enter image description here][1]

Comment: Did you mean to put a link to your image?

Comment: Please upload your image to Imgur and add it to your post as `[1]: URL`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't highly enough recommend this video by Uncle Bob:

[Robert C Martin(Uncle Bob) -Clean Architecture and Design - Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=asLUTiJJqdE)

Among other great things you can learn from it, specifically for your question, the takeout is that your database design should be **deferred** as much as possible. You are better off seeing your DB as some sort of abstract interface and start with your business logic. That will polish your understanding of what you really need from the database, what sort of API can be useful for your logic to communicate with it. It looks like you are getting stuck precisely because you try to nail down your DB structure before developing your business logic.

To give you a more concrete idea for your question, you probably need a table 
`PRODUCTS`, where you have `product_id`, `name`, etc. Now you seem to have one-to-many relation to `PROD_SIZES`, which can be another table with `prod_size_id` or whatever as *primary key*, `product_id` as *foreign key* and `size`, `price` as regular fields. However, you could instead compress your `size`-`price` pairs as `JSON` and place it inside another field of your `PRODUCT` table. That will really depends on your business logic.

If you store the same item in several locations, you probably need another table `LOCATIONS` with all info you need about each location. Then you have a many-to-many relation between `prod_size_id` and `location_id`, which is a separate `hash` table having `id`, `prod_size_id`, `location_id`, and `nr_of_units`. Now to move some units from one location to another, you only mess with the last table by changing the last column.

Hope it helps.